# Creating an album-centered app -- is RSS the only way to go?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, rss

Trying to create an iOS (iphone) app centered around a photo album that will be updated daily. New to this. Learning coding slowly. First, I'd like some advice - anyone know what the best way to go about this would be? Should I take the RSS route and implement an RSS feed from some album site? Is there a way to do it that depends less on an account made with another site? Even a blog rss would be better because at least I'd have full control over the blog.

I find that implementing an RSS feed for a photo blog site still ends up creating a look that is more article style - where each post is listed with post time, date, header, etc., rather than a thumbnail click-to-expand album style.

I'll be implementing getsocialize so that each photo can be liked, tweeted, etc.

Some guidance in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you creating the photo album site, using something like flickr/tumblr, or hosting your own open source photo site like coppermine?  For your iOS app, all you need is some "web service" from the photo site to get your data, whether it is RSS, or some RESTful service to retrieve the data.  Once you have the data, you can display it in your iOS app however you want.  The RSS or web service would just be the transport to get the data to your app, not the end look and feel on your iOS app.  Any additional information would be helpful here.